# Como obter resultado da seleção do menu gdialog na variável em Shell Script?

Tags: script, shell, shell-script

Estou criando um `script` simples para aprendizado no qual o usuário deve:

- Digitar número que será salvo na variável NUM1
- Digitar um segundo número que será salvo na variável NUM2
- Escolher no menu se ele quer somar, subtrair, multiplicar ou dividir esses números.

Após esses procedimentos, deverá aparecer no terminal  "A opção escolhida foi: soma (como por exemplo, se ele tivesse escolhido subtração, apareceria ali subtracao [sem acento porque é a variável que quero que apareça]).

Código que criei:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

NUM1=$( gdialog --inputbox "Informe o número 1"
gdialog --title 'Aviso' )

NUM2=$( gdialog --inputbox "Informe o número 2"
gdialog --title 'Aviso')

escolha=$( gdialog \
           --menu 'Escolha:' \
           0 0 0 \
           soma '+' \
           subtracao '-' \
           multiplicacao '*' \
           divisao '/' )

echo "A opção escolhida foi: $escolha"

exit
```

**Problema:**
Quando eu executo, faço todos os procedimentos como usuário até a escolha no menu, aparece no terminal o que foi escolhido, porém, não é o que eu pedi para aparecer e logo em baixo aparece "A opção escolhida foi:" e não aparece a variável na frente.

Eu gostaria que essa variável aparecesse para eu ver que ela realmente está sendo salva em $escolha, para que eu consiga encontrar uma maneira de usar o switch case e terminar o meu script.

OBS: Uso gdialog para modo visual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resposta curta: O gdialog manda a saída para e STDERR; portanto precisas de redirecionar o STDERR para a STOUT ou seja juntar `2>&1` às invocações de `gdialog`:

```
escolha=$(gdialog .......... 2>&1)
```

---

Eventualmente espreita o **zenity**

```
num1=$(zenity --title "Aviso" --entry --text "numero 1")
```

Como uma filosofia ligeiramente diferente, sugiro o **gtkdialog**

```
#! /bin/bash

export MAIN_DIALOG='
 <vbox>
  <hbox>
    <entry> <variable>E1</variable> </entry>
    <entry> <variable>E2</variable> </entry>
  </hbox>
  <hbox>
    <button> <label>+</label> <action> echo $(($E1+$E2))</action> </button>
    <button> <label>-</label> <action> echo $(($E1-$E2))</action> </button>
    <button> <label>*</label> <action> echo $(($E1*$E2))</action> </button>
    <button> <label>/</label> <action> echo $(($E1/$E2))</action> </button>
    <button ok></button>
  </hbox>
 </vbox>'

gtkdialog --program=MAIN_DIALOG
```

Answer (score 4):

Tomei a liberdade de alterar seu script pra um modo mais simplificado e legível, ficando assim:

```
#!/bin/bash

operacao=""

echo "Digite o primeiro valor"
read valor1
sleep 3
echo ""
echo "Digite o segundo valor"
read valor 2
sleep 3
echo ""
echo "Escolha a operação: "
echo "1 - soma"
echo "2 - Subtração"
echo "3 - Multiplicação"
echo "4 - Divisão"
read operacao
case $operacao in
    1) operacao="Soma" ;;
    2) operacao="Subtração" ;;
    3) operacao="Multiplicação" ;;
    4) operacao="Divisão" ;;
    *) echo "Opção inválida" ; exit ;;
esac

echo "A opção foi: $operacao"
```

Comment: Sem problemas, rsr... Mas é que eu queria no modo visual, dai o gdialog ajuda nisso.

Comment: Entendi, eu não conheço esta função ainda.

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigada... ;)